# Can alignas be implemented with mmap?

Tags: c, memory, mmap, memory-address, alignas

I was wondering if someone can try to implement alignas with mmap by playing with the first parameter? If not, then can anyone try to implement alignas themselves?

Comment: Using `mmap()` would be a runtime operation.  A standard implementation of `_Alignas` is a compile-time operation.  Why would you need to implement `_Alignas` rather than using what the compiler provides?

Comment: Please give a specific example such as "I want to heap allocate a 5 KB object with 64 byte alignment on x86-64."  So far this sounds like an X-Y-I-don't know problem.

Comment: To do this dynamically, how about `posix_memalign`?